# Will the workflow evaluates the record based on its duration trigger the mail?

Tags: workflow, email-alert

Hi This is the workflow rule I have set to trigger the mail if the conditions are met.
[image]

Suppose if the case is created and it was not edited until 5 days and the case was not edited . will the workflow trigger email by evaluating the case duration.

If i Keep the Logic as 1 AND 2 OR 3.

Revised Time Based workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No it will no.

What you are trying to do use time based workflow. Run this workflow on creation and set the email after five days and use your required criteria.

If in between record failed to match criteria then email will not be send.

Comment: I tried time based workflow by selecting the third option in the evaluation criteria. and set the email alert after 5 days the case Date/Time-Opened. the rule is if priority is normal and Case status is not equal to closed then trigger the mail.However if the case closed before 5th day also the the email is getting triggered saying case is opened.

Comment: @SuelRobert can you please check again also try using only first criteria

Comment: if  i use first criteria it will evaluate the record only at the time when the record is created right . so even if I set the time based  workflow to 5 days. Will it re-evaluate the record to check whether the status is not equal to closed?

Comment: @SamuelRobert for both questions yes

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the Time based workflow. Please review it.

Comment: hi I have tried the way you said ,Still the workflow is triggering the mail on the 5th day even if the condition is not met.